# Screenshot are not showing up on plugin page

Tags: plugin-development

I know its quite common now, But I cant find out where I am doing wrong. I have screenshot placed at the right place (both trunk and tag/1.0 ) and used the same tag i.e 1.0 in readmen.txt but still they are not showing up on plugin's screenshots tab.

Read me file
http://plugins.svn.wordpress.org/nextgen-3d-flux-slider-template/tags/1.0/readme.txt

Plugin page.
http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/nextgen-3d-flux-slider-template/screenshots

Can anyone notice a problem somewhere?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think there's a problem with your .png's. Are they truly .png files, or possibly .jpg/.gif just renamed to .png? Try saving as a .gif or .jpg and re-upload.

Sidenote: unless you need your users to have the screenshots in the plugin .zip, you can upload them to the SVN assets directory instead, and it won't be included in the .zip. See [Otto's post](http://make.wordpress.org/plugins/2012/09/13/last-december-we-added-header-images-to-the/).

Comment: Yes, they are truly png images. I just uploaded it to assets directory. Lets see if they show up.

Comment: You are very much right. Moving images to assets directory fixed it.

Comment: Glad that worked for you. :) It's strange, though...unless something's changed since Otto's post, it should've worked in *either* place. Oh, well...I'm too lazy to look it up.